# How to properly sort Graphql query results into categories, such as organizing blog posts by category

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am working on a Gatsby site for a freelance writer. I am using Sanity as the CMS. I am working to sort and organize a list of their published writing by category, not by date. My code works but is not very robust as you will see.  I am thinking there is a more effective way of accomplishing what I want to do. I am thinking the answer would be obvious here to someone more experienced with nested loops in react.

I have been experimenting with a variety of loops and keep running into problems when I try to nest the loops to capture the results of both the `cats` variable and the `writing` variable.

```
const publishedList = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allSanityPublishedWork {
        nodes {
          title
          category
          id
          publishedBy
          publishedDate
        }
        distinct(field: category)
      }
    }
  `);
  const writing = data.allSanityPublishedWork.nodes;
  const cats = data.allSanityPublishedWork.distinct;
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{cats[0]}</h3>
      {writing
        .filter(pub => pub.category === cats[0])
        .map(pub => (
          <p>{pub.title}</p>
        ))}
      <h3>{cats[1]}</h3>
      {writing
        .filter(pub => pub.category === cats[1])
        .map(pub => (
          <p>{pub.title}</p>
        ))}
      <h3>{cats[2]}</h3>
      {writing
        .filter(pub => pub.category === cats[2])
        .map(pub => (
          <p>{pub.title}</p>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default publishedList;
```

As you can see in my code example I rely on specifying the array number like so `cats[0]` which is not a robust way to accomplish this as I need to know the exact number of categories which could change over time.  There should be a way to loop through my results from this query and do the following in a more efficient and resilient way than I have done above:

- Category Heading

  - Article Name, Date, Published By
  - Article Name, Date, Published By
  - Article Name, Date, Published By
- Category Heading

  - Article Name, Date, Published By
  - Article Name, Date, Published By
  - Article Name, Date, Published By
- Category Heading

  - Article Name, Date, Published By
  - Article Name, Date, Published By
  - Article Name, Date, Published By

Etc.

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for this?

```
cats.map(cat => (
  <>
    <h3>{cat}</h3>
    {writing
      .filter(pub => pub.category === cat)
      .map(pub => (
       <p>{pub.title}</p>
    ))}
  </>
))
```

Still, if you can influence how GraphQL schema looks like, I would highly recommend you to design your schema in a way that fits more your needs.

Comment: That did it - I tried a few versions similar to that but must have had something not quite right or missing in my code because I was getting an error.  I really appreciate the help!